# IntelliJ Refactor to use LoD

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, automated-refactoring, law-of-demeter

Say I have some class Foo

```
class Foo {
    protected String x = "x";

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

I have a program that uses Foo and violates LoD

```
class Bar {
    protected Foo foo;

    public Bar() {
        this.foo = new Foo();
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    String x = bar.getFoo().getX(); 
}
```

Refactoring to use LoD looks like this:

```
class Bar {
    protected Foo foo;

    public Bar() {
        this.foo = new Foo()
    }

    public String getFooX {
        return foo.getX();
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    String x = bar.getFooX();
}
```

IntelliJ-IDEA has a lot of refactoring methods (e.g. extract to method, extract to variable, inline).

Is there a method in IntelliJ-IDEA that will refactor code like `bar.getFoo().getX()` to look like `bar.getFooX()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your example is Java code, you could do the following:

1. Extract method on `bar.getFoo().getX()` (creating `getFooX()`)
2. Move the created method `getFooX()` to `Bar` if necessary
3. Invoke *Find and Replace Code Duplicates* on `getFooX()`
4. Invoke *Convert To Instance Method* on `getFooX()`
5. Optionally Structural Replace `$a$.getFoo().getX()` with `$a$.getFooX()` if you forgot step 3;-)
6. Inline all invocations of `getFoo()` (should be only in `getFooX()`)

Comment: I was able to do it in only two steps. 
1. Extract method (find and replace shows up automatically)
2. Move method (convert to instance method shows up there)

Comment: Here is a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213864/custom-refactoring-methods-intellij)

Comment: Yes, you're right of course, the *Convert To Instance Method* does the move implicitly. Good find. Edit: wait a minute, you do the *Move* and *Convert To Instance Method* show up? Not for me. And the duplicate finder that shows up automatically only searches in the same file for me...