# Simple Custom Refactoring in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, automated-refactoring, law-of-demeter

This question is a follow-up [for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191880/intellij-refactor-to-use-lod).

Say I have some class Foo.

```
class Foo {
    protected String x = "x";

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

I have a program that uses Foo and violates LoD ([Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).

```
class Bar {
    protected Foo foo;

    public Bar() {
        this.foo = new Foo();
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    String x = bar.getFoo().getX(); 
}
```

I can refactor this code to use LoD in two steps.

1. <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> `bar.getFoo().getX()` -> `getFooX(bar)` (extract to method, also find and replace occurrences)
2. <kbd>F6</kbd> `getFooX(bar)` -> `bar.getFooX()` (move to instance method, also find and replace occurences)

The program that uses `Bar` no longer violates LoD.

```
class Bar {
    protected Foo foo;

    public Bar() {
        this.foo = new Foo();
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public String getFooX() {
        return foo.getX();
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    String x = bar.getFooX();
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make a custom refactoring method in IntelliJ that would consolidate these two steps into one.

**EDIT**
I got a reply from JetBrains with a link to a pre-existing feature request. Please vote on it if you find this useful!

> Hello Michael,
>
> Seems we have similar request in YouTrack:
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122400. Feel free to vote
> for it and leave comments.
>
> Best regards, Yaroslav Bedrov JetBrains

**EDIT**
There is at least a way to inspect for Law of Demeter issues.
[image: screenshot]

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/MichaelSnowden/b117a039a58b8350c9cd) that contains an inspection profile that will just look for LoD violations. You can [import it into IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customizing-profiles.html#d1529343e18640).

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to accomplish in one step with current IDEA version (v14), I didn't find any appropriate single command. It might be a good idea to submit a feature request if this function is really missing.

Comment: @erkfel I's currently being reviewed. The link doesn't look active yet, but it should be here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/66429

Comment: @erkfel See my edit, and checkout https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122400

Answer (score 3):

After adding the `getFooX()` method to `Bar`, I would use **Edit** > **Find** > **Replace Structurally** with the following expressions:

Search template:

```
$instance$.getFoo().getX()
```

Replacement template:

```
$instance$.getFooX()
```

It does the job perfectly. Maybe you can add some constraints to `$instance$` variable to narrow the search but that would only be useful if you had multiple classess with that method name.